# Can't find my SQL server instance in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I'm having problems finding a SQL server in Azure portal. The SQL server is apparently running as I can connect to it with both AzureAD credentials and SQL credentials via SSMS. The apps using databases from the SQL server is also working.

But I can't find it in Azure? I've tried checking portal.azure.com with all our logins, but no luck.

Anyone has any tips?

Comment: That's really strange. can you share a screenshot of the list of databases in the portal if possible?

Comment: There's nothing there. It's just "Welcome to Azure! Start with a free Azure trial".

Comment: Double check if you have chosen the same directory and subscription under you account if you have more than one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to log in with my admin account and go to portal.azure.com/customer.domain

Answer (score 0):

Double check if you have chosen the same directory and subscription under you account if you have more than one. And If you remember your resource group name, just to rule out any transient issue in web portal, you can try the below:

Install Azure CLI from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli) or use cloud CLI and run below commands in order

Login to your account, result lists all the subscription in your account.

```
 az login
```

Verify your preferred subscription is set

```
az account show
```

See your SqlDB details:

```
az sql db show  --name YourSqlDbName --server YourSqlServerName --resource-group YourResourceGroupName
```

You'll see all he details, if it exists.